# ServletActionContext.getRequest().removeAttribute() not working

Tags: java, servlets

i am removing some attributes from `ServletActionContext` bu later on when i iterate the `ServletActionContext` the attributes keep showing.

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest().removeAttribute("myCategory");
ServletActionContext.getRequest().removeAttribute("title");

for (Enumeration e = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameterNames();  e.hasMoreElements();) {
    parameterName = (String) e.nextElement();
    parameterValue = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter(parameterName);
    System.out.println(parameterName +":"+ parameterValue); 
}
```

and  console keeps showing me `myCategory:something` and `title:otherthing`

can any one see what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you removed is `attribute`, but you are displaying `paramater`. These are two difference variables.

Check [ServletRequest.getParameterNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames%28%29) and [ServletRequest.getAttributeNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttributeNames%28%29)

Comment: thnx, so how should i remove paramater?

Comment: You can't. Parameters are immutable.